# Getting "TypeError: must be a string, not function"

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm using a microcontroller to control a lightbulb based on a user input time, and I'm running this function in a thread. I keep getting an error at the line `time.sleep(1)`:

> TypeError: must be a string, not function

```
def light():
    while True:
        if(hour < 7 or hour > 18):
            digitalWrite(light, LOW)
        elif(hour > 6 and hour < 19):
            digitalWrite(light, HIGH)
        time.sleep(1)
        increment_second()
        print second

#Time increments
def increment_minute():
  global minute
  minute = minute + 1
  if(minute == 60):
    minute = 0;
    increment_hour()

def increment_hour():
  global hour
  hour = hour + 1
  if(hour == 24):
    hour = 0

def increment_second():
  global second
  second = second + 1
  if(second == 60):
    second = 0
    increment_minute()
```

This is my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/cloud9/Untitled2.py", line 63, in light time.sleep(1)
TypeError: must be string, not function
```

Comment: Add try and except maybe helps.

Comment: So it looks like the error is somewhere else in your code, where you maybe redefine `time` as something else than the standard module. (You should check this is not the case).

Comment: Clear your definition if you have a name `time`. Or `from time import sleep as zzzz` and `zzzz(1)`

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase  Hi Kevin, this is my traceback:  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/cloud9/Untitled2.py", line 63, in light
    time.sleep(1)
TypeError: must be string, not function`

Comment: Function name "light" and then variable "light" ? Why same?

Comment: @dsgdfg I tried that, but it gave me the same error.

Comment: @DineshPundkar Wow good catch! Variable light was set to my GPIO pin - I forgot to change the function name.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was caused by me accidentally naming a variable and the function the same name. Changing the names fixed it. Thanks everyone for your help!